# Python __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, oop

I want to create an little discord bot with python that make a money system...
I also have no idea how to make the transfer function to tranfer money from one acoount to another.
I always get this error: TypeError: **init**() missing 4 required positional arguments.Can somebody help me? Here is my code:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name, age, email, gender):

        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.email=email
        self.money=50
        self.accs=3
        self.gender=gender

    def überweisen(self, money):
        self.money=self.money-money

    def __del__(self):

        print("Acount von wurde gelöscht!")
```

Comment: Are you passing the arguments `name, age, email, gender` when creating the `User`?

Comment: So user creation should look like `myUser = User(name="Mike", age="30", email="Mike@TestUser.com", gender="Male")`